# Why is import Text.RawString.QQ failing?

Tags: haskell

Following both Haskell documentation and SO answers, I try to

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Data.RawString.QQ
```

I can't get further than `Could not find module ‘Text.RawString.QQ’` Do I need a dependency - how to I look up which one?

Comment: You need to install the corresponding package, for example with `cabal install raw-strings-qq`.

Comment: This package [contains the `Data.RawString.QQ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq-1.1/docs/Text-RawString-QQ.html) module.

Comment: Thank you, now I notice `raw-strings-qq-1.1` in top left corner of http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq-1.1/docs/Text-RawString-QQ.html.

Comment: Alternatively, `stack install raw-strings-qq`